# I am having trouble multiplying two matrices with numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to use numpy to multiply two matrices:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1, 3, 2], [4, 0, 1]])
B = np.array([[1, 0, 5], [3, 1, 2]])
```

I tested the process and ran the calculations manually, utilizing the formula for matrix multiplications.  So, in this case, I would first multiply `[1, 0, 5] x A`, which resulted in `[11, 9]`  and then multiply `[3, 1, 2] x B`, which resulted in `[10, 14]`.  Finally, the product of this multiplication is `[[11, 9], [10, 14]]`

nevertheless, when I use numpy to multiply these matrices, I am getting an error:

```
ValueError: shapes (2,3) and (2,3) not aligned: 3 (dim 1) != 2 (dim 0)
```

Is there a way to do this with python, successfully?

Comment: please provide the code you used for the multiplications

Comment: check dimensions of the intermediate matrices you are getting

Comment: Did you try trabsposing one of the arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the docs on [matrix multiplication in numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html), specifically on behaviours.

> The behavior depends on the arguments in the following way.
>
> If both arguments are 2-D they are multiplied like conventional
> matrices. If either argument is N-D, N > 2, it is treated as a stack
> of matrices residing in the last two indexes and broadcast
> accordingly. If the first argument is 1-D, it is promoted to a matrix
> by prepending a 1 to its dimensions. After matrix multiplication the
> prepended 1 is removed. If the second argument is 1-D, it is promoted
> to a matrix by appending a 1 to its dimensions. After matrix
> multiplication the appended 1 is removed.

to get your output, try transposing one before multiplying?

```
c=np.matmul(A,B.transpose())

array([[11, 10],
       [ 9, 14]])
```